# Как прочитать цифры из файла, чтоб вернулись типом int?

Tags: java, массивы, кодировка, методы

Например `read()` класса FileInputStream возвращает байтовые значение симолов. Мне нужно, чтобы 3 в массива заносилась как 3. 
Примечание: файл передается аргументом главной функции (args[0])

Comment: А у вас текстовый формат файла или бинарный?

Comment: @VladD Да, текстовый

Comment: Тогда вам нужно и читать его **весь** как текстовый. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716521/276994

Comment: Тогда получится целый текст, как я смогу занести каждую цифру в отедльный элемент массива?

Comment: Ну, а что в файле?

Comment: @VladD В файле цифры:
1122
4455
и т.д.
Мне нужны именно эти цифры, по отдельности, чтобы в каждый элемент массива запихнуть и работать с ними дальше ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, так:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(path)))
{
    while (scanner.hasNextInt())
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, работает ли для многострочного файла — у меня нет под рукой компилятора Java

Comment: `add` cannot resolve method

Comment: @UliyanRomanov: А какого типа ваш список?

Comment: Спасибо, использовал сканер, только чуть по-другому. `mas[i]=scanner.nextInt();`